# Many operations with DataContext

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, design-patterns

I'm using EF for developing and enough new here.
I'm confused with how to work with EntityFramework context when I have to do different operations with context. Could you give me good tutorials and glance at my code for finding possible issues

Now I have next code

```
//domain.dll

class OrderDomainService 
{
   public void DoWork()
   {
     foreach(var order in GetOrders())
    {
       DeleteOrder(order);
    }

   }
   public List<Order> GetOrders()
   {
      IOrderRepository orderRep = new OrderRepository();
      return orderRep.GetAll();
   }

 public void DeleteOrder(Order order)
   {
      IOrderRepository orderRep = new OrderRepository();
      return orderRep.Delete(order);
   }
}

//repository.dll

public interface IOrderRepository
{
   List<Order> GetAll();

   void Delete(Order order);

   void SaveContext()
}

public class OrderRepository
{
 public OrderRepository()
{
   if (ctx == null) 
    ctx = new EntityFrameworkDataContext();
}

   static EntityFrameworkDataContext ctx { get; set; }

   public List<Order> GetAll()
   {
      return ctx.Orders;
   }

   public void Delete(Order order)
   {
      ctx.Orders.Delete(order);
   }

   public void SaveContext()
   {
     ctx.SaveChanges();
     ctx = null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to share same `EntityFrameworkDataContext` instance between between several repositories (Use unit of work pattern http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx ).Because if you are doing an operaiton which you need to initiate two or more repositories you will have problems.